# How to get upcoming live event feed for a particular YouTube channel in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm working on an hybrid/mobile app using the jQuery Mobile framework and I want to retrieve a live events feed (upcoming or featured) from a particular user/channel. I tried something in this way: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/albpower2/events.

And I got a

> Developer key required for this operation

message.

I created a I developer key but I don't know how to include into this URL API call.

UPDATE:
I found something for Youtube v3 Data API and from their online API testing platform it works, but when I try to execute that functions directly from the browser it says OAuth athentication needed. I don't know how to set up that OAuth key and get the function working from the url

From this GET Request `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet&broadcastStatus=all&key=AIzaSyDhDZjburmzpaoH39Uj4dnU6X_GRLbCVW0`
 this is the response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I'm getting these informations from this link: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.liveBroadcasts.list?part=snippet&broadcastStatus=all&_h=19&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a more natural way to work this out but I ended with an improvisation, instead of retrieving Live events feed from a channel I am creating manually an playlist and after creating an event I add it there and from there I display to the app. So for now its working solution till there is an javascript solution for API v3 to solve this with creating automatically Access tokens.

So for retrieving items from playlist using API v3 the method is something like this: 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={your_playlist_ID}&key={your_API_KEY}

Answer (score 2):

Just include it in the URL of the API call:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/albpower2/events?key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

<sub>From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).</sub>

Comment: The solution you provided doesn't work it says (I modified the API key at the url): 
**Invalid request URI**

See the updated question for the new error using Youtube API v3

Comment: I solved it in some manner but after some time now it doesn't work.. why is that?

Comment: @albpower I used the wrong operator - you might want to take a closer look at those docs to make sure you're requesting the right data; I'm not sure why it would just stop working unless you used your entire quota, though.

Comment: As I see it the Access token expires automatically approximately after 1 hour. This is not good practice for my mobile app in jquery mobile because after expiration of the token there are no datas avalaible at the feed